# Entender o uso de generics em uma classe abstrata DAO Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, genéricos

Olá,

Estou a começar a desenvolver uma aplicação web com framework spring+hibernate, comecei por um exemplo que continha seguinte classe:

```
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public abstract class AbstractDao<PK extends Serializable, T> {

    private final Class<T> persistentClass;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AbstractDao(){
        this.persistentClass =(Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getByKey(PK key) {
        return (T) getSession().get(persistentClass, key);
    }

    public void persist(T entity) {
        getSession().persist(entity);
    }

    public void delete(T entity) {
        getSession().delete(entity);
    }

    protected Criteria createEntityCriteria(){
        return getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass);
    }

}
```

É um DAO abstrato para ser usado para os restantes DAOs, não consigo perceber os genéricos que a classe recebe:

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<PK extends Serializable, T>
```

E a linha que está no construtor

```
this.persistentClass =(Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
```

Não estou confortável com genéricos em java. Conseguem dar uma ajuda explicam a lógica desta classe?

Obrigado.

Comment: A linha que você achou complicada é uma gambiarra para contornar o _type erasure_ do Java. Como o Java apaga a informação do tipo genérico, é necessária essa gambiarra para saber qual ele é.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

Esta classe está desta maneira para que novos DAOs possam passar diferentes entidades ao *extender* esta classe e, assim, reusar os métodos desta classe abstrata.

Por exemplo, se você tem uma entidade `Pedido` (`T`), no qual a chave primária (`PK`) é um objeto do tipo `Long` e deseja criar um DAO para ela, o código ficaria:

```
class PedidoDao extends AbstractDao<Long, Pedido> {

}
```

Após isto, você pode usar na classe `PedidoDao` os métodos de `AbstractDao`, e estarão todos aderentes a particularidade da sua entidade `Pedido`.

Sobre o código específico do construtor:

```
this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
```

A primeira parte:

```
(ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()
```

É usada para pegar o tipo de classe parametrizável (`ParameterizedType`), que contém informações de `PK` e `T`. Mas como o código deseja pegar a entidade `T`, ele usa:

```
getActualTypeArguments()[1]
```

Pois na posição `[0]` está a `PK`.

Answer (score 0):

Esses vão ser tipos declarados pelas classes que extenderão o seu DAO.

Suponha que você crie um DAO concreto para trabalhar com uma entidade `Book`. Ele deverá ser declarado de foma parecida com:

```
public class BookDao extends AbstractDao<Long, Book> {
    ...
}
```

Todas as referências aos tipos `PK` e `T` agora serão dos tipos `Long` e `Book`, respectivamente. E o seguinte trecho de código será válido:

```
BookDao bookDao = new BookDao();
Book myBook = bookDao.getByKey(100); // Aqui, getByKey aceita um Long e retorna um Book
```

É o mesmo conceito utilizado com `List` e `Map`, por exemplo. Para criar um `ArrayList` de String, você deve invocar:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
// O metodo add recebera somente strings agora
strings.add("Hello");
```

Se você buscar a fonte da classe `List`, verá que ela foi declarada de forma genérica:

```
public interface List<E> extends Collection<E> {
    ...
}
```

---

A linha do construtor é uma forma de buscar, em tempo de execução, a classe do tipo genérico `T`.